# Facebook/Instagram android in-app(webview) browser won't allow access to the microphone in my web app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, facebook, webview, instagram

I'm building a speech enabled web app using vue.js, so far it works perfectly on major browsers and devices like Chrome, Safari, Firefox, Opera, etc however if someone accesses the link from Facebook or Instagram using an Android, there are issues.

The facebook/Instagram inapp browser(webview) doesn't let us ask for microphone permission.

I'm looking for a solution which forces the user to open the app in their main browser instead of staying in the Facebook/Instagram app.

Please assist me with this issue.

Comment: Whether links open in the in-app browser or an external one, is a [user setting](https://www.ricksdailytips.com/force-facebook-app-to-open-links-in-browser/) - I don't think there is a way to _force_ it from your end. At most you can try and detect that your page is running in the in-app browser - and then show a message to the user, saying that they need to go and open it in a real browser instead, if they want to be able to use that feature.